# Offline WSUS delta updates

Tags: wsus

I have a secure (not connected to the internet) system that needs to be kept up to date via WSUS. We have installed a WSUS server on it and have copied over 20+GB of update content and imported the corresponding configuration for them.

Now, a month later, we want to only add the 27 new updates from Microsoft, but we can't figure out a way of exporting only the new changes from out internet connected WSUS machine so we don't have to impex the whole 20+ GB again.

Is this supported by WSUS (Server 2008 R2)?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you can chose exactly which updates should be downloaded using [WSUS Offline Update](http://www.wsusoffline.net/). But at least you can download the patches and delete everything unwanted.

Comment: [WSUS Offline Update](http://www.wsusoffline.net/) does not have anything to do with what is asked here — it is a program to install security updates **without** WSUS server, and the question is about using an actual WSUS server in a disconnected environment.

Answer (score 0):

[The Microsoft documentation on using WSUS in a disconnected environment](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939873%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) has only this suggestion for update files:

> You can use the Windows Backup Wizard or any other file transfer utility to transfer update files from the WSUS export server to removable media. Consider using an incremental backup method to limit the data that you must transfer every time that you refresh the WSUS import server.

and nothing at all for update metadata:

> Although you can use incremental backup and restore functions to import update files to the WSUS import server, you cannot incrementally transfer the update metadata.

Instead of using a full-featured backup program, you can use any utility which can synchronize directories without copying files which already exist in the destination directory — e.g., [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) or [Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy).